# ¿Por qué se muestra el registro de la búsqueda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy empezando en el tema de la programación en Rails.

Resulta que estoy desarrollando un app de prueba, donde tengo un modelo Song y otro Album. En el controlador de Album tengo una función 'show', la que me permite mostrarlo, ¿verdad?

El punto está en que cuando accedo a la página del álbum, me aparecen las canciones (como es de esperar), pero también me aparece una especie de log de la búsqueda que se hizo.

#### Controlador Album

```
    class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /albums
    # GET /albums.json
    def index
      @albums = Album.all
    end

    # GET /albums/1
    # GET /albums/1.json
    def show
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
      @songs = Song.where(album: params[:id])
    end

    # GET /albums/new
    def new
      @album = Album.new
    end

    # GET /albums/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /albums
    # POST /albums.json
    def create
      @album = Album.new(album_params)
      @album.cover = params[:album][:cover]
      @album.save

      respond_to do |format|
        if @album.save
          format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @album }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /albums/1
    # PATCH/PUT /albums/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @album.update(album_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @album }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /albums/1
    # DELETE /albums/1.json
    def destroy
      @album.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to albums_url, notice: 'Album was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:nombre, :cover)
      end
  end
```

#### Show.html.erb (Album)

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1><%= @album.nombre %></h1>
<img src="<%= @album.cover.url %>" alt="">

<%= @songs.each do |d| %>
  <p><%= d.nombre %></p>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="<%= d.audio.url %>" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_path(@album) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', albums_path %>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin más que decir, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en:

```
<%= @songs.each do |d| %>
```

debería ser:

```
<% @songs.each do |d| %>
```

En general cuando usas `<%=` es para retornar un valor, el cual será rendereado en el html que genera, mientras que `<%` se usa en ocasiones en que no necesitas el valor, como en una iteración con un `.each`.

Comment: Que vista @AlterLagos !!!

Comment: ¡De maravilla! Muchas gracias (!)